# Fill part of a shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, segment

Could you please tell me how to fill the highlighted area with gray!60?
Thank you so much!

[image: Current output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[thick,fill=gray!30](0,0) circle (2);
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2.2);
%
%
\draw[thick](-0.3,-3.2) -- (2.8,-0.5);
%\draw[thick](-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[thick](1.4,-1.7) -- (0.9,2) -- (-1.94,1.02) -- cycle;
%
\node[left] at (-1.93,1.02) {\large $P$};
\node[right] at (0.81,2.2) {\large $R$};
\node[left] at (-0.25,-3.3) {\large $S$};
\node[right] at (2.7,-0.3) {\large $T$};
\node[below] at (1.55,-1.65) {\large $Q$};
%
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't fiddle around with so many manual coordinates.

You can use polar coordinates `(<angle>:<distance>)` and then you know the specific angles already and use them with the `arc` operator.

The [`turn` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#tikz/turn) helps finding the tangent at `Q` very easily.
It basically sets up a coordinate system where its origin is at the last point and the *x* axis points in the direction of the previous path segment.
In our case, this is just the move to `Q` from the center.

I'm also using a `label` on the coordinates to directly place the label.

---

With the `ext.paths.arcto` library of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) you can even simply say

```
\fill[gray!60] (Q) arcto (R) -- cycle;
```

Note, however, that I put `radius = 2.2` as an option to the picture so that any radius for `circle`, `arc` or `arcto` is set and doesn't have to be specified more than one – well except for the polar coordinates.

Otherwise you would need to say `(Q) arcto[radius=2.2] (R)`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.arcto}% for the arcto path operation
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2.2]
\path[font=\Large]
 coordinate[label=above:$R$]           (R) at ( 68:2.2)
 coordinate[label=left:$P$]            (P) at (150:2.2)
 coordinate[label=below right:$Q$]     (Q) at (-53:2.2)
 (Q) coordinate[label=below left:$S$]  (S) at ([turn]-90:2)
     coordinate[label=above right:$T$] (T) at ([turn] 90:2)
;

%\fill[gray!60] (Q) arc[start angle=-53, end angle=68] -- cycle; % arc
\fill[gray!60] (Q) arcto (R)-- cycle; % arcto
\draw[thick, line join=round]
  (R) -- (P) -- (Q) -- cycle
  (S) -- (T)
  (0,0) circle[];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are right, if one starts to define coordinates first, it is only consistent to define coordinates for *S* and *T* beforehand as well ... and use actual `label`s =)

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use polar coordinates and define them beforehand. This way, it is much easier to later add stuff to the existing drawing. The degree values in the following code are approximations, which is why the result is slightly different from yours.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, font=\large]

% define coordinates for origin as well as for P, Q and R
\coordinate (o) at (0:0);
\coordinate (p) at (155:2.2);
\coordinate (q) at (-50.5:2.2);
\coordinate (r) at (65:2.2);

% draw the section to be filled first in order to place it in the background
\fill[gray!60] (r) arc[start angle=65, end angle=-50, radius=2.2] -- cycle;

% draw the circle
\draw (o) circle (2.2);

% draw the tangential line in two steps using the coordinate for Q and attach labels to it
\draw[blue] (q) -- ([turn]90:2) node[above right] {$T$};
\draw[blue] (q) -- ([turn]-90:2) node[below left] {$S$};

% draw the triangle using the above defined coordinates and attach labels to it
\draw[red] (p) node[left] {$P$} -- (q) node[below right] {$Q$} -- (r) node[above right] {$R$} -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!